# Error while I launch spark-submit because avro

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, avro

I am creating an application in spark.
I use avro files in HDFS with Hadoop2.
I use maven and I include avro like this :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I did a unit test and while I use mvn test, all work.
But While I launch with spark submit no ! 
and I have this mistake :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat.createRecordReader(AvroKeyInputFormat.java:47)
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
I fond the solution :D 
Thanks to http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Fwd-Unable-to-Read-Write-Avro-RDD-on-cluster-td10893.html.

The solution is to add jar in your SPARK_CLASSPATH

```
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=yourpath/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar:yourpath/avro-1.7.7.jar
```

You can download the jar here : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.7.7/

Comment: you can as well update the same in you config file extraclasspath

Answer (score 0):

But it isn't a solution with spark-submit --master yarn-cluster

I have again the same error :

WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 15, 10.163.34.129): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat.createRecordReader(AvroKeyInputFormat.java:47)

Someone has another idea ?